# Not getting partial video content while using ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to partially send a video using nodejs and `fluent-ffmpeg`. But it's failing to send the data.

When I send the video using only `fs` module only, it works fine. Here's the code.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();  
const fs = require("fs");

const VIDEO_PATH = 'video.mp4';

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.get("/video", (req, res) => {
  const range = req.headers.range;
  if(!range) {
    res.status(400).send("Requires range header!");
  }

  const size = fs.statSync(VIDEO_PATH).size;
  const CHUNK_SIZE = 10**6;
  const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ""));
  const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, size - 1);

  const contentLength = end - start + 1;

  const headers = {
    "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`,
    "Accept-Ranges": 'bytes',
    "Content-Length": contentLength, 
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
  }

  res.writeHead(206, headers);

  const videoStream = fs.createReadStream(VIDEO_PATH, {start, end});
  videoStream.pipe(res);
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port: ", 3000);
})
```

When I send the video after processing it using `fluent-ffmpeg` module, it doesn't work. I've simplified the code for understanding. Here's my code.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();  
const fs = require("fs");
const ffmpegStatic = require('ffmpeg-static');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegStatic);

const VIDEO_PATH = 'video.mp4';

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.get("/video", (req, res) => {
  const range = req.headers.range;
  if(!range) {
    res.status(400).send("Requires range header!");
  }

  const size = fs.statSync(VIDEO_PATH).size;
  const CHUNK_SIZE = 10**6;
  const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ""));
  const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, size - 1);

  const contentLength = end - start + 1;

  const headers = {
    "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`,
    "Accept-Ranges": 'bytes',
    "Content-Length": contentLength, 
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
  }

  res.writeHead(206, headers);

  const videoStream = fs.createReadStream(VIDEO_PATH, {start, end});

  ffmpeg(videoStream)
    .outputOptions('-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov')
    .toFormat('mp4')
    .pipe(res);
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port: ", 3000);
})
```

My `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="video-player" width="50%" controls>
    <source src="/video" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.